# Where does paging, sorting,and search go in repository pattern?

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

I have a repository class. I want to add paging, search and sorting to this class. How can I do it?

```
 public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly DatabaseContext _context = new DatabaseContext();

        public IQueryable<T> GetAll(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
        {
            IQueryable<T> dbQuery = _context.Set<T>();
            dbQuery = includeProperties.Aggregate(dbQuery, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
            return dbQuery.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();
        }
}
```

Comment: Not related but: If you accepts `Expression` and return `IQueryable` you will gain nothing of Repository pattern. Repository pattern should abstract database access, but with expressions and queryable you are leaking database implementation details back to the domain logic.

Comment: Paging: add parameter which tells how much records to skip, Order: add parameter to tell property to use and direction, Search: add parameters to describe values to search for.

Comment: Entity framework is already a repository Pattern and you can also naturally use Skip And Take. I'm not sure who is promoting this pattern with EF these days, but i would seriously look up the pros and cons before you get too far. It can easily hinder development and can turn into a mess. Also for a philosophical discussion of patterns and design, Software Engineering SE site is a great place

Comment: @TheGeneral I wish they'd add a big disclaimer to every page of the EF docs indicating that EF is already a repository+UoW. Not gonna happen, but it'd be nice... So many people seem to overlook this fact (granted I'm sure there *is* some legitimate use case for adding the extra abstraction, but at least for the general case it  holds true)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 agreed. Yeah i think the problem was it promoted by a couple of very influential people back-in-the-day to solve certain design issues, though the world moved on. Teachers educators and blogs are still out the promoting these patterns for EF on out dated firmware. Although there is many ways these patterns can be useful, 9 times out of 10 they are misused and quite frankly cause more problems then they solve.. all in my opinion though

Comment: @TheGeneral, if you want to have "freedom" to choose technology for data persistence during application lifetime, then having EF as persistence layer abstraction can be very complicated. EF cannot be considered as abstraction, because it obviously leaking database structure details to the domain layer (DbSet properties). Repository pattern should be driven by domain type systems.

Comment: For example `OrderRepository.Save(order)` - `order` object can have properties `ShippingAddress`, `BillingAddress` of type `Address`, but in database 
 all address information can be saved in one record of `Order` table. With EF this kind optimization will involved much more work then just introduce new implementation of `OrderRepository.Save(order)`

Answer (score 3):

#### Opinionated Answer directly relating to the Question

With respect to .NET and the Repository Pattern, *in general* try and make your methods return an `IQueryable`. This enables you to 'chain' up a linq query which you can then chain common expressions like paging and sorting to. This means you can re-use these methods more and more and stop yourself from writing heaps of custom methods that will be used once or twice. The exception to this case (there's always an exception, right?) would be when you need to hit some specific performance metrics (eg. this code needs to run FAST and therefore the DB query needs to be fast/specific).

In your code example above, you've started to do this:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAll(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties) { .. }
```

This enables you to reuse the `GetAll` method for various other usages. Paging? sure. Ordering? OK, let's also order. You can in fact use all the normal linq-extensions that are found with IQueryable and based upon the underlying repository used, the results can be filtered appropriately.

Usually this would mean that your method will end up doing the database call and then the results will then be further manipulated by the chained methods, but again this depends on your implementation inside the `GetAll` method.

So in summary -> do **not** do paging/sorting/aggregations in your Repository pattern methods as a general rule as this will lead to higher-reuse and less specific-hardcoded methods.

On the flip side, you should have specific methods that do include sorting or paging if you're going for a specific performance related metric. For example, you might be wanting to query a specific Stored Procedure or custom SQL query or custom DocumentDB Index (yes, the Repository Pattern can be used against other repositories besides Relational DBs like Microsoft SQL Server. It can be used against DocDb's or even a filesystem!)

#### Opinionated Answer with respect to .NET + EF + Repository Pattern

Please don't use the Repository Pattern, here. Like some of the comments to the OP have stated, if you're using EF, then *that* is actually a Repository Pattern and an Unit of Work already done. In the old days, people added their *own* Repository Pattern over EF because of the failings of EF in the BadOldDays(tm) .. mainly with respect to unit testing/integration testing.

We've all moved on. EF has matured (supposedly). You don't really need to do this now.

Oh - and the chance that you're doing a Repository Pattern because "you might switch databases in the future" is usually unlikely. People *rarely* switch out database and if they end up doing that, they usually have way more problems that wishing they used a Repository Pattern.

Finally, *yes* there are some scenarios where the Repository Pattern is advantageous but nothing IMO was stated that might hint that this might be the case, so I'm going to assume it's not. HINT: an app like an offline mobile device that might be using different databases per mobile app OS .... maybe .....

#### Final Note

This entire answer can be pretty much debated as opinion. When working with the Repository Pattern + .NET there's some *general* suggestions (i.e. my first half of the answer) but then we always have the opinions stated in the 2nd half of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to suggest something different to the answer and comments that are already here. Rather than having a generic repository, where you're trying to fill the use cases of all data access, create different repositories whose design is driven by your domain's needs.

IMO, the generic repository causes more problems than it solves:

- What if one entity doesn't require delete functionality?
- What if one entity doesn't need a `GetAll` method?
- `IQueryable<T>` is a leaky abstraction

Generic repositories only make your design harder to evolve, because you end up having to implement all of those methods for any given situation, no matter what the actual requirements are, and people can still lean heavily on the returned `IQueryable<T>` leading to querying logic bleeding between layers.

Instead, you can easily do something like the following:

```
public interface ICustomerRepository
{
    Customer Get(string id);
}
```

Once you have a few repositories in place like this, the cost of creating others is significantly reduced. Especially if you implement this using something like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) and make use of [Dapper.Contrib](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib), implementing focused, expressive repositories that are easy to create, test and consume, becomes a breeze.

Comment: When you apply SOLID (the L mostly)  then some of your objections can be addressed by refactoring into IReadOnlyRepository, IUpdateRepository etc.  But that gives you a more granular generioc repository, the rest of the discussion remains.